# How I can change positions between panels on Portal Demo of Ext js?

Tags: extjs4

I would like to know how I can do that the panels on extjs'portal demo – change positions between them. Example: If panel A is dragged and dropped over the position of panel B, panel B changes its position to the position of panel A.

Comment: Please provide what you've done so far. To do that.

Comment: the code of extjs'portal  [demo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/portal/portal.html) is in the extjs4's documentation, in that example when I drag and drop  a panel, it insert in the position of another panel. I want that the other panel change his position with the old position of first panel .

Comment: you can use [`Ext.dd.DropZone`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dd.DropZone) , [`Ext.dd.DropTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dd.DropTarget), `Ext.dd.*` and more. you need to read it carefully to do that. :)